# Animate UIView to grow and shrink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UIView`.

How can I animate this view that the view gets bigger (width, height) and then is reduced again to its original size?

Answer (score 6):

Simple way to animate grow and shrink with CAKeyframeAnimation

```
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")

    animation.values = [1.0, 1.2, 1.0]
    animation.keyTimes = [0, 0.5, 1]
    animation.duration = 1.5
    animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    view.layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

Comment: Works great! The best solution IMO!

Answer (score 4):

Swift Answer...

**Swift 2**

```
//Get Smaller
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
self.view.frame.size.height -= 100
self.view.frame.size.width -= 100


})
//grow
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
self.view.frame.size.height += 100
self.view.frame.size.width += 100


})
```

**Swift 3,4,5**

```
//Get Smaller
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.view.frame.size.height -= 100
    self.view.frame.size.width -= 100


})
//grow
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.view.frame.size.height += 100
    self.view.frame.size.width += 100


})
```

Comment: How would you combine both animations to make it first bigger than shrink to its original size?

Answer (score 4):

Simply do a `UIView animation` using the scale property of transform.

Objective-C:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                 animations:^{
                     yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                      animations:^{
                                          yourView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

                                      }];
                 }];
```

Swift 3.0:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
}) { (finished) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
        yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })
}
```

`CGAffineTransformMakeScale` scales your view and `CGAffineTransformIdentity` reverts the view back to its original form.

Answer (score 3):

Simply apply a `UIView` animation, then apply the reverse of the animation to get back the original view.

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1.0
                               delay:0.0
                              options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                           animations:^{

                              myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,300);

                           } completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];
```

Comment: Wen do you apply the reverse?

Comment: Whenever you want, just apply the reverse frame that you want inside the animation block of that code.