# Maximising and Shrinking Animation for iOS Application

Tags: ios, animation, geolocation, icons

Can anybody tell me how to make such animation in a App:

Looked for it everywhere, couldn't find anything

[Example screen recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iyly30xsf5f1xh/User_annotation.mov?dl=0)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248758/animate-uiview-to-grow-and-shrink

Comment: @vp2698 Thats for the animation overall, but how would it work if we had 100 users at the same location